# How do you get the cursor position in a react TINYMCE

Tags: reactjs, position, tinymce

I'm user react TinyMCE , I want to get cursor position and insert a string to this position. Help me, thank all!

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an 2-year-old question, but since I stumbled upon it having the same problem, and the provided answer was not about React, this is how I solved it:

I'm using tinymce with the useRef-hook, hence I have

```
const editorRef = useRef(null);
...
<Editor onInit={(evt, editor) => (editorRef.current = editor)} ... />
```

then I can call the tinymce-api-function [insertContent](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#insertcontent)

```
editorRef.current.insertContent("text to insert");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to insert content at the current cursor's location you can use the `insertContent() API call:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#insertcontent

For example:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.insertContent('<span>This is content to insert</span>');
```

If you have a selection in the editor this will replace that content. If you don't have a selection this will be inserted where the cursor is located.